# No file or directory: 'ffmpeg' on MacOS in Python

Tags: python, macos, apple-silicon, openai-whisper

I am using MacOS (Apple Silicon) and I am trying to use the whisper module from OpenAI in Python. My code is this:

```
import whisper

file_path = "4547.mp3"
model = whisper.load_model("base")

result = model.transcribe(file_path)
print(result["text"])
```

When running that code I get the error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ffmpeg': 'ffmpeg'
```

I think it is because Python is looking in the wrong folder for ffmpeg and therefore can't find it, but I don't know how to fix that if that is the issue.

I have installed homebrew and used the command 'brew install ffmpeg' and it has successfully installed with no errors. I have tried uninstalling ffmpeg and reinstalling it, uninstalling open_whisper and reinstalling it, and installing ffmpeg-python but it still doesn't fix this issue.

Answer (score -1):

The library you're trying to use requires another package or another app named *ffmpeg* . Just install it it must fix the issue.

First try installing ffmpeg package within python by running this command :

```html
pip install ffmpeg
```

If that doesn't work try downloading ffmpeg app for your os which is macOS  and install it and run the code again. I found [this guide](https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ffmpeg#How_to_Install_FFmpeg_on_macOS) on how to install package manually, hope it helps. Thank You.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I used the link provided and downloaded it manually and it successfully downloaded. The code errors the same way still. I don't know if this helps, but when I put 'which ffmpeg' into the terminal it said that ffmpeg is located under '/opt/homebrew/bin/ffmpeg'

Comment: if it was windows, putting ffmpeg in same directory solves the problem. But it's a mac and I've abit less idea how that works. Have you tried installing pip too? Note : pip and ffmpeg executable are two different things.

Comment: Yes, I have installed pip, and it is on the latest version.